# Handle single tap on LayerColors in Cocos2d-x 3.0

Tags: touch, cocos2d-x

I have a LayerColor subclass called MyLayer. I have a few instances of MyLayer in the scene. I want to tap each instance and do something for just that instance.

I set-up the touch handling like this:

```
    EventListenerTouchOneByOne *listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(MyLayer::touchBegan, this);
    listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(MyLayer::touchEnded, this);
    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

Then I handle touches with these methods:

```
    bool MyLayer::touchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *event) {
        Point touchPoint = this->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());
        return this->boundingBox().containsPoint(touchPoint);
    }

    void MyLayer::touchEnded(Touch *touch, Event *event) {

    }
```

Problem is touchEnded is not called correctly. It works for one MyLayer instance but the other instances never receive touches.

I logged the bounding box and touch point. For the instances of MyLayer that don't receive touches the touch point and bounding box are "mixed-up": touch points that would be in a bounding box are passed to touchBegan for a different bounding box. Hence touchBegan returns false.

I'm using Cocos2d-x-3.0rc1. Any help is appreciated!

Also, the touch handling for other LayerColor subclasses works fine with the same code used above. However, I only have single instances of those subclasses in my scene while I have multiple instances of MyLayer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best think to do is rearrange your code a bit, consider:

```
auto listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

listener->onTouchBegan = [&](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    return true;
};

listener->onTouchEnded = [=](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    MyLayer::touchEvent(touch);
};

void MyLayer::touchEvent(cocos2d::Touch* touch)
{
    cocos2d::Point p = touch->getLocation();
    cocos2d::Rect rect = this->getBoundingBox();

    if(rect.containsPoint(p))
    {
      // you touched it, now do something
    }
}
```